# Wordpress default template seems not to be index.php or page.php

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, default

I am trying to modify the default page template in wordpress.
I have tried index.php and page.php, but when I remove the header from the template or type in a die(), the page in the browser doesn't change at all.

Any ideas? What can the default template be?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Depends what page you are looking at, category, archive, single post, single page, home page...

Comment: I just did a get_page_template() and returned page.php. But when i do the modification they don't show up...

Comment: "I have tried index.php and page.php" in which directory? Are you aware that each template has its own directory?

Comment: could be cashing problem if you are using super cash plugin or similar

Comment: @Sébastien what do you mean by 'templates have their own directory'?

Comment: in WordPress each template sits in a dedicated directory inside the "themes" directory (like `/wp-content/themes/my_template/`)

Comment: get_page_template returns C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject/wp-content/themes/enfold/page.php

Comment: @Sébastien you mean `/wp-content/themes/my_theme/` all template files are in the root of the theme, by default

Comment: @secuaz only thing that comes to mind if it s not caching issue, which happened to me few times, is that theme you are editing is not activated in the admin...